# Show Div When Click Link Button

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

Am new to Asp.Net. In My Application i need show the name of user in menu when click user name show sub menu with sign out. So i tried like this

```
 <div id="DivRight">
   <ul> <li><asp:LinkButton ID="lblusername" CssClass="imjusttext"
   ForeColor="#1570a6" Font-Underline="false" Text="Admin" OnClientClick="return false"  
    runat="server"/></li></ul>
 </div>
 <div id="DivSubMenuRight" style="display:none" runat="server">
   <ul> <li><asp:LinkButton ID="lblSignout" CssClass="imjusttext" ForeColor="#1570a6" 
   Font-Underline="false" Text="Sign Out" OnClientClick="return false"  runat="server"/>
   </li></ul>
</div>
```

I need click event in server code so i use `linkbutton`.

**ASP.NET**

```
   Protected Sub lblusername_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
 Handles lblusername.Click
        DivSubMenuRight.Visible = True
    End Sub

Protected Sub lblSignout_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
    Handles lblSignout.Click
         FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    End Sub
```

**CSS**

```
.imjusttext{ color: #1570a6; text-decoration: none; }
.imjusttext:visited { color: #1570a6; text-decoration: none; }
```

**EDIT**

when i click username then show div like when we hover some tag name here its show rectangle box in black color. like that. how to do it ? And I need to right sign out click event in server side coding for user authentication so how write it. Because its a link button?

am using **ASP.NET 2008**

Comment: Why u are not using proper menu control, add UserName as top and LogOut as child/sub menu. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecs0x9w5.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Jquery` to show/hide for element when clicking. Here is the basic example.

```js
$('.submenu a').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find('ul').toggle();
  return false;
});
```

```css
ul li ul{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="DivSubMenuRight">
  <ul>
    <li class="submenu"><a href="google.com">Signout</a>
      <ul>
        <li>sub menu 1</li>
        <li>sub menu 2</li>
        <li>sub menu 3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i have updated my answer, this is the basic example of showing an element when click on another.

Comment: thanks for your valuable time. but i need to show div sub menu for sign out. and when i click sign out button its not working. so can you tell for that    and thanks sir

Comment: ok, but not clear you question. in which item show for click on which element?

Comment: did you see sign out menu in any other site. like that.

Comment: check my answer, this is the basic functionality, and if you want a styled dropdown menu then you should learn css&html or hire a web designer.

Comment: "did you see sign out menu in any other site. like that", If this is the case then you please tell what do you need, tell about the website (for layout)  which functionality you want to copy to yours.

Answer (score 0):

In default you use hide property to hide div tag, then you can use show() property in jquery on clicking username

```
  $('#DivSubMenuRight').hide();
  $('#user_name').click(function()
  {
      $('#DivSubMenuRight').show();
  });
```

Comment: you can use href attribute to set link path for redirection to your default page on clicking signout link

Answer (score 0):

Give some id to usrname link

```
$("#lblusername").on('click',function(){

   $("#DivSubMenuRight").show();;
})
```

In singout link put `href="javascript:void(0)"` to avoid default behaviur

```
$("#lblSignout").on('click',function(){

  // call your signout url
})
```